# What are the Alternative for JSONPath({json: obj, path: path, callback: callback}) function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using [JSONPath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONPath)

```
JSONPath({json: obj, path: path, callback: callback})
```

in my nodejs code for getting path/value of particular element in the JSON, but it has some performance issue. Can anyone suggest to me an alternative for this jsonpath function?

Comment: Can you specify the performance issues. How big is the JSON document you are parsing? What is the path you are querying?

Comment: The size of json can be more than 15mb.

Comment: I think documents that big are going to give you slow queries with any library. Can you explore other optimisations, such as caching parts of the document for where you need it?

Comment: Can you show us some of the JSON format, because this issue will need some optimization, not some other 3rd party library?

Comment: Store them in MongoDB and then make a query

Comment: I found one web site "https://jsperf.com/jspath-vs-jsonselect/4" which provide other libraries which are similar to JSONPath but anyone of them are not much flexible as compare with JSONPath library

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's highly optimized and uses iteration instead of recursion. Also there are lots of examples provided.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const haystack = { a: 0, b: 'bar' };

const r = objectScan(['**'], {
  joined: true,
  filterFn: ({ value }) => typeof value === 'string'
})(haystack);

console.log(r);
// => [ 'b' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)